# grid view not showing responsiveness

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, responsive-design

I am **making a website responsive** having master page and content pages.

It works fine on pages with basic asp.net controls like Textbox, Checkbox and buttons.

But it **does not apply to pages in which grid view is bounded**.

Here is the code below I have added to master page and all the aspx pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
```

and below is the code I added in stylesheet:

```
#main { width: auto; margin: auto;}
```

Below are the snapshots of **data grid not showing responsiveness**:

before scaling browser window:

[image: before scaling browser window]

after scaling browser window:
[image: after scaling browser window]

Do I need to make more changes or I have to add more stylesheets?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering what steps you have taken to make the gridview table intself work well on narrow screens?

See if these two links are helpfull:
[how to add responsive behaviour to gridview](http://bit.ly/WG7gND)
[jQuery responsive table plugin](http://bit.ly/WG7sfX)

Good luck!

Comment: That's great, just what we like to hear.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#main 
{ 
 width: 960px; 
 margin:0 auto;
 overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply..but its not working properly..for screens like desktop its showing margins on both left and right sides..trimming the content.

Comment: try the firebug for set the design in FF.

Comment: I am a newbie and i have never used firebug, can u explain  how do i use it?

Comment: Press F12 in any browser and select your element than set your design according to you. install firebug for Firefox.