# gridview not responsive when the screen becomes smaller

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview, responsive-design

I have a gridview on my web page. When I make the screen smaller, half of the gridview is going beyond the page. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

below is my code:

```
           <div style="margin-left:25%;">
                    <asp:GridView RowStyle-Wrap="false"  ID="grdCalculate"  runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" CssClass="grid" OnRowDataBound="grdCalculate_RowDataBound" class="table table-responsive" >
                     

                    </asp:GridView>
```

how can I make the grid responsive. I am already using the jquery plugin like so on my master page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-responsiveTables.js"></script>
```

The above script tags are not making any difference to the responsiveness of the gridview.

I already saw this URL, but it didn't help me:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195985/grid-view-not-showing-responsiveness
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have bootstrap and jQuery installed?

Try this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="HotelName"
            CssClass="table table-responsive">
```

So, table, and table-responsive

in fact, even with just table in above, it re-sizes rather nice.

[image]

And going as small as possible, I get this:

[image]

Comment: when you click on F12 and see the same grid in Mobile version then the grid goes outside the page

Comment: Well, that may be the case, but you not going to get any better resizing of the grid then what above shows - not matter how supposed "responsive". You can perhaps shrink down the size by reducing the div size for the page, but there are limits as to how small the grid can shrink.  Given typical phone browser resolutions are quite good, that grid should display ok - but as noted, you only going to get/see it go so small.